# Geofence Process against Legitimate MitM

Tags: man-in-the-middle

We are developing a solution where a door is controlled by a backend that is publicly available over the 4G network (there is no local network available at the place of deployment).

The user is scanning an NFC tag that is next to the door and thus gets the id of the door and the URL of the backend (both values have to be considered public, because once you were there, you know them).

Using this backend, the user can authenticate and open the door.

Our **problem** now is, that we do not want a remote user, who knows both the door id and the backend URL, to open the door for a local user, who is at the door.

We would prefer not to use geofencing mechanisms like GPS (can be spoofed) or Bluetooth beacons (we are afraid that these will mean cumbersome and bad/lagging user experience).

One idea we had is to use FIDO2 authenticators at the doors (thereby kind of abusing the FIDO-way of authenticating). However, since the remote user can just send all challenges to the local user at the door (whom he wants to grant access remotely), these seem to not work either.

It got me thinking that I have myself **a sort of legitimate man-in-the-middle** here. The remote user starts a legitimate process, and whatever challenge the backend sends to him, he can just pass on the the user at the door who is going to solve the challenge locally, and send it back to the remote user, who can then convince the backend that he is actually at the door, which he is not.

Do you know of a similar case that has already been solved? Do you have any idea how to solve it, or is our way of thinking fundamentally flawed?

Any help and insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it an option to have the "server" responsible for unlocking the door located on-site and not internet-enabled?  That's probably the only way to do it.

Comment: I guess this boils down to a relaying problem. The local user could still relay all the requests back to the remote user and vice versa, sitting in between the backend and the remote user.